# Powershell SQL returns

Tags: sql, powershell

I am trying to view the results of a sql query into a remote server.  My issue is that on return i see the first value repeated for each of the other values.

Here is the code:

```
#Connect to VPN
cls
C: 
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client"
& ".\vpnclient.exe" connect WWVPN1 user sceris pwd ******

$vendorNumber = "2130196"
$vendorName = ""
$invoiceNumber = "1362433"

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=wwfinance; Initial Catalog=ScerIS; Integrated Security=False; uid=Peter; pwd=*****; MultipleActiveResultSets=true")
## Open DB Connection
$conn.Open()

 $sqlText = "SELECT UdiValue1, UdiValue37, UdiValue38, UdiValue3
             FROM ScerIS.dbo.indexedRangesView_4
             WHERE (UdiValue37 like '%$vendorName%' OR UdiValue38 like '$VendorNumber') AND UdiValue3 = '$invoiceNumber'"

    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlText, $conn)

    $Reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

  while ($Reader.Read()) {
     $ArchiveDate = $Reader.GetValue($1)
     $VendorNumber = $Reader.GetValue($2)
     $VendorName = $Reader.GetValue($3)
     $InvoiceNumber = $Reader.GetValue($4)
    }

    write-host $ArchiveDate
    write-host $VendorNumber
    write-host $VendorName
    write-host $InvoiceNumber


    $conn.close()


    #Disconnect from VPN
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client"
& ".\vpnclient.exe" disconnect
```

The output will show the archive date 4 times once for each write-host.  How can i successfully get the other values to display?

Sample Output

9/4/2015 12:00:00 AM
9/4/2015 12:00:00 AM
9/4/2015 12:00:00 AM
9/4/2015 12:00:00 AM

Comment: You're not writing anything until after you've looped through the entire result set.  `$ArchiveDate`, `$VendorNumber`, `$VendorName`, and `$InvoiceNumber` are all going to have the value of the last iteration of the loop.  Given what you're doing here, I might use a [DataAdapter instead of a DataReader](https://powershellreflections.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/using-powershsell-to-access-sql-data/), but its not clear what you're trying to display or why.

Comment: Even if it is the last iteration of the loop that wouldn't explain why Archive Date get's written out 4 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, and `$4` are never defined.  If you want to get the values from the first 4 columns use:

```
while ($Reader.Read()) {
  $ArchiveDate = $Reader.GetValue(0)
  $VendorNumber = $Reader.GetValue(1)
  $VendorName = $Reader.GetValue(2)
  $InvoiceNumber = $Reader.GetValue(3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason i was under the impression that those were special powershell syntax like $true or after a -match you can use $Matches.  not sure why though